# How to retrieve data from SQLite Database in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve some data from my table in my database. [This is the table I am trying to retrieve data from, which is called mon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFKde.png) This is the code I wrote:

```
    let db = new sqlite.Database('./linksdb.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE);

    let sql = `SELECT subject FROM mon`;

    db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row.name);
        });
    });
```

After I execute this, it says this in the cmd:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

What have I done wrong or what do I need to change? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `console.log(row.subject)` - the column you selected is named 'subject' not 'name'.

Comment: I think row maybe an array inside foreach

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was logging the wrong thing, instead of doing row.subject I did row.name.
Thanks for the help!